# Exclude thumbnails current post from query

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I created a Custom Post Type (CPT) called "Employees".
In this CPT I created posts like "Max", "Phil", "Denise" etc.

All these posts have a featured images attached.

I created a query to grap all featured images from the posts in CPT "Employees".
This works great. All thumbnails are loaded.

The problem is that I want to exclude 1 featured image. That's the one when I'm in a post from the CPT "Employees".

Let's say I'm going to the post "Max".
All featured images of all other posts in the CPT "Employees" have to be loaded, except the one from Max.

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
            $args=array(
            'post_type' => 'employees',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'include' => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
            'posts_per_page' => -1
            );

            $my_query = null;
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {                             
                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        ?>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </a>
            </div>

        <?php  endwhile;
                    }
            wp_reset_query();
       ?>
```

I tried to exclude the current post thumbnail by adding 
    'exclude' => $post->ID,
to the arguments, but that's not working.

Maybe someone can help me with this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **`'post__not_in' => array(get_the_id())`** in you query. It will do the job :).

The value of `"post__not_in"` must be an array of ids. So in your case, the id of the current post. **get_the_id()** will get it.

```
 <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'employees',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'include' => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__not_in' => array(get_the_id())
    );
```